# ajax and $.getScript() to get a new script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getscript

I'm trying to add a js function dynamically so I read about `$.getScript()`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems `$.getScript()` will just call a .js file that's already there in the public folder and will just sort of "load it" and make it available, but the js file itself being called is just a static js. What I'm trying to do is call a dynamic js script and the content of this js script changes considerably, so it has to come from the server.

- I think this isn't possible with `$.getScript()` alone, or is it?
- If not, I could make an ajax that returns the function syntax, but how do I then add it somehow to the current js or how do I create a js file for it and load that js?
- I would possibly like to delete the new js later, but that's not a priority.

So can `$.getScript()` help with this or a combo of `$.getScript()` and .ajax?

Comment: What are you using to serve the dynamic script?

Comment: @Pekka I will formulate the js function `function test(){ }` and return this script from a php server. It's not clear yet whether I'll need to return it as a .js file or as just the text of the function definition, but both can be done as needed I think.

Comment: just point to the PHP file, the file's extension is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pekka's comment is correct - jquery doesn't care what the extension of the file is.

$.getScript("dynamicScript.php") will work just fine so long as that file outputs valid script (no script tags needed)

Comment: So when I call this file, does the js content get stored somewhere so it's available for the site, or I would have to call it every time I need it?

Comment: functions, variables, etc will be stored to memory on execution providing they aren't destroyed implicitly or by scopes. If you use an OO pattern and for example your script returns an object literal like: `window.APP={...}` it _should_ be available for the remainder of the session until destroyed. It would need to be loaded for every user in every call-situation. It will not be cached by default.